# Running armhf Debian 9 (Stretch) inside Docker on an arm64 Debian 9 system

Tags: docker, arm, embedded-linux, arm64

I lately tried to compile some Debian package natively on some low-end ARM board with only 2 GB RAM using `dpkg-buildpackage`. The [CMake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMake) build runs quite some time, but it is getting slower and slower until it breaks (after some hours) due to low memory. This is because the code of the application is quite complex C++ code that includes a lot of stuff and statically links nearly each and everything. This unfortunately can not be changed.

My intention is now to run it on some large scale cloud ARM server (96 cores, 128 GB RAM), but it runs some arm64 [Debian 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Debian_9_(Stretch)) (Stretch).

Is it possible to run a Debian 9 [armhf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture_family#Floating-point_(VFP)) system on some Debian 9 arm64 server?

If yes, how would it look like to set it up?

Comment: Unfortunately some 64-bit ARM CPUs including the Cavium ThunderX are 64-bit only. I have not been successful in finding a 32-bit capable ARM cloud server.

Comment: Thanks, this problem ist exactly what I see now. Qemu seems also not being able to run it on that cloud server. This it what qemu-debootstrap returns after stage 1: `I: Running command: chroot stretchtest /debootstrap/debootstrap --second-stage
chroot: failed to run command ‘/debootstrap/debootstrap’: Exec format error`

Comment: Not an answer to my question, but a solution to my problem was, to use Clang/LLVM for my build. It was using much less memory than GCC and succeeded in the end to compile the whole project, but It was complaining about some implicit casts, which needed to be fixed by an explicit `static_cast` to work.

Comment: Amazon Web Services now provide cloud servers capable of 32-bit ARM user mode.

Answer (score 0):

On the [ARMv8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_ARMv8-A_processors) high-end-servers (e.g., [Cavium ThunderX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ARM_processors#Designed_by_third_parties)), it is not possible to run [armhf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture_family#Floating-point_(VFP)) code, since these [SoCs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_on_a_chip) are AArch64 only, but [QEMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QEMU) seems not aware of this. If you try to run a [chroot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) with QEMU (e.g., with *qemu-debootstrap*), it also fails. I believe QEMU could be improved to detect this situation and emulate the 32-bit ARM correctly, but obviously it doesn't.

On low-end ARM-v8-SoCs (e.g., Cortex-A53) supporting both AArch32 and AArch64, I believe, it should work out of the box. Example: [single-board computers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-board_computer) are the [Raspberry Pi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Raspberry_Pi) 3 and the [Pine64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pine64).